# Fixed size array in PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.
I want create an array with a fixed size, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE eco.test ( 
    id           text  NOT NULL,
    test_array   integer[3],
    CONSTRAINT pk_aircrafts PRIMARY KEY ( id )
 );
```

That is, I want the size of test_array will be 3.

But, I can make this:

```
INSERT INTO eco.test(id, test_array) VALUES ('1', '{1,2,3,4}')
```

And everything will be fine.

```
select * from eco.test;
id | test_array
'1'   {1,2,3,4}
```

How can I make a fixed size array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a [`CHECK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) that forces `array_ndims(test_array) = 1 AND array_length(test_array, 1) = 3`.

Comment: alternatively use `cardinality()` with 9.5

Comment: Is this still the best answer in 2021?

Comment: @elimisteve To my knowledge, yes.

Comment: As of Postgresql 16, still the same. You can check at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html. As of today: "[...] However, the current implementation ignores any supplied array size limits, i.e., the behavior is the same as for arrays of unspecified length."